# copy paste Range in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy paste a row of values from one sheet to another but keep coming up with the run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error.
the error is in the first line of the two below and I do not know where I am going wrong.

```
Set copyRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").range(A & i + 1 & CA & i + 1)
copyRange.Copy Destination:=Cells(countD, 2)
```

the code needs to copy a line at a time and paste it into the default sheet.

**Edit**
full code

```
Dim List1 As range
Dim List2 As range
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim countD As Integer
Dim found As Boolean
Dim copyRange As range

Set List1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").range("H2:H600")
Set List2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").range("I2:I600")
countD = 2
lastRow = Application.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").range("C:C"))

For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    found = False
    value1 = List1.Item(i, 1)
    For Each value2 In List2
        If value1 = value2 Then
            found = True

            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If found = False Then
        Set copyRange = Sheets("Sheet1").range("A" & i + 1 & "CA" & i + 1)
        copyRange.Copy Destination:=Cells(countD, 2)
        Sheets("Discrepancies").Cells(countD, 1) = "name not found"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        Cells(countD, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

        countD = countD + 1

    End If

Next
```

Comment: Try range("A" & i + 1 & "CA" & i + 1)

Comment: nope, does not work either, same error code

Comment: I would suggest providing your full code...to identify the actual error....

Comment: What does the value `A` and `CA` contain? If that should refer to column A an column CA, try `Set copyRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").range("A" & (i + 1) & ":CA" & (i + 1))`. This will cover the entire area from A2 to CA2 (assuming i is 1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exactly as Vasim's comment mentions - with the addition of a colon `:` in front of the `CA`

```
Sub copyRangeOver()

Dim i As Integer
i = 6

Dim copyRange  As Range
Set copyRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i + 1 & ":CA" & i + 1)

Dim countD As Integer
countD = 10
copyRange.Copy Destination:=Cells(countD, 2)


End Sub
```

Comment: (@Vasim sorry for coping and pasting your comment! ... let me see if I can make it up to you...) ; now you've jumped to 300 points!!!