# What do I need to do in order to structure these results?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to learn VBA, but it's very different from the type of programming I'm used to. For that reason I would appreciate your guidance.

I want to structure the results I get from simulations. There are screenshots below illustrating what I'm trying to describe with words here:

What I want to do is:

1. Copy all the results from one sheet to a new sheet (to keep the original data).
2. Delete certain columns, for instance `B & D:E`
3. Move (or copy, doesn't matter) rows `30:38` up besides rows `11:19`, with one empty column in between. The result will be as shown in the last figure below. (The number of rows in each block varies, and there are 4 blocks).

I don't know if these are the recommended procedures, but I know I can:

**Delete columns** [this way](http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/delete-rows-columns/):

```
Sub sbDeleteAColumnMulti()
Columns("D").Delete
End Sub
```

**Copy/paste a range** [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18504948/2338750):

```
Sub copyRangeOver()

Dim i As Integer
i = 6

Dim copyRange  As Range
Set copyRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i + 1 & ":CA" & i + 1)

Dim countD As Integer
countD = 10
copyRange.Copy Destination:=Cells(countD, 2)

End Sub
```

- A few things that is complicating stuff for me: The headers (except the first one): `Bus  ( A  ) -LL Fault`, are shifted one column to the right (they are now above `Ik''`, not `Bus Name`).
- I don't know in advance how many rows are in each "block", thus I need to check this (but I know there are only 4 "blocks"). All "blocks" are the same size, so I can just check the number of rows between two `Bus Name`s.

Now, **I don't want someone to write me a code!** What I hope someone will help me with is to suggest a procedure I can follow for this to work. I know that many roads lead to Rome, and I see that this question might come of as either a "Primarily opinion-based question", or "Too broad". However, I think it's a legitimate question that belongs here. I'm not trying to start a debate over what the "best" way of doing this is, I just want to find a way that works, as I currently don't know where to start. I'm not afraid of "the complicated way", if it's more robust and cleaner.

**What I don't know is** what kind of `Modules`, `Class Modules` (if any) etc I need. Do I need Collections, create `Public`/`Private` subs? What would be the purpose of each of those be in this case?

**What I start with:** (Edit: none of the cells are merged, it's just a bunch of whitespaces)

[image]

**What I want:**

[image]

## Update:

Here's the first chunk of code I get when recording a macro (note that my workbook has more columns and rows than in the example I gave):

```
Range("D:I,K:M,O:P").Select
Range("O1").Activate
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=39
Range("C52:E78").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-42
Range("G13").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=84
Range("C91:E117").Select
```

To me, this looks like a piece of crap. Of course, it's possible that I should have created the macro differently, but if I did it the right way, I don't think it's much to work with. I guess I can delete all the `SmallScroll`-lines, but still...

Also, I don't see how I can adapt this, so that it will work if I have a different number of rows in each block.

Comment: This is twice as hard as I thought when I started reading. That's because not only are you starting with a clunky format that includes merged cells, but you want to convert it to another non-tabular (clunky) format that includes merged cells. My main tip would be to try to get this all into a normalized table that you could then report off of in whatever format you want.

Comment: @DougGlancy: Thanks for reading through it! I see now that it looks that way, but none of the cells are merged, it's just a bunch of white spaces (and I don't want merged cells in the results either). I probably should have made that clear in the question text. What do you mean by a normalized table?

Comment: That's good news about the lack of merged cells. That way you can at least start by deleting the empty columns. My reference to a normalized table meant that I'd try to end up with a four-column table that looks like one of your result tables, with the addition of a "Fault Type" column. You could then use pivot tables or lookup functions to report on the data in the normalized table. I think :). In response to your comment that you deleted, yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this, you're going to want to start with using the [Macro Recorder](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html) from Excel.

If you are doing the exact same formatting options for the exact same data output each time, this is by far your best bet. The recorder will copy whatever you do for formatting and write the code you need. It may not be the *best code* but it will by far be the *best option* for what you are describing.

If (when?) you need to start adding logic other than the same formatting, you will then have functional code which will make your life easier.

---

#### But isn't the macro recorder going to generate bad code and/or it's better to just code from scratch?

I'm fairly experienced at this point and often use the macro recorder because... while it does put a lot of code there which isn't strictly speaking necessary, it gets you a ton of the more obscure stuff (how do I format the cell border to be this way?) etc. Of course it's better to not only use the recorder, but for your example it's even more perfect, you get all the formatting recorded and then can modify the logic and not have to waste time figuring out syntax for formatting, deleting columns, etc.

Very few languages offer the ability to basically say, "I want to do what I am doing now programmatically - how can I start?" the way VBA does. You can bypass a lot of annoying syntax issues when learning (especially if you've previously done any sort of coding) and focus right on the logic you want to add. It works out pretty well, honestly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it! My main objective is not really to do this operation (although it will be nice to have it automated), but to learn how to write VBA. Although this operation might be a bit tricky, it should be a fairly simple if I only knew what (and how) to write (what I need to include in the code). Do you know if it's possible to get a dynamic range by just recording macros? Optimally I want a function that says: `For i = 2 To 4, Move/Copy desired columns in Block i up`. That is: I don't want to hard code any row numbers.

Comment: The reason why I haven't tried a macro for this yet is because my intuition tells me (that in most cases) the code will be much better if written by a programmer from scratch, rather than being created by a computer and then altered by a programmer to make it fit better. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: It depends on the programmer :). Sorry, couldn't resist. Even experienced VBA programmers take advantage of the Macro Recorder as a starting point, often because they don't know the right syntax, or, as Enderland is saying, because there's a bunch of repetitive steps and recording will give you a quick start. You can always improve the generated code by getting rid of `Selects` and `Activates`, eliminating unneeded function arguments and fixing the formatting.

Comment: You can't get dynamic ranges through the Macro Recorder.

Comment: @RobertP. - I'm fairly experienced at this point and often use the macro recorder because... while it does put a lot of code there which isn't strictly speaking necessary, it gets you a ton of the more obscure stuff (how do I format the cell border to be this way?) etc. Of course it's better to not _only_ use the recorder, but for your example it's even more perfect, you get all the formatting recorded and then can modify the logic and not have to waste time figuring out syntax for formatting, deleting columns, etc.

Comment: Very few languages offer the ability to basically say, "I want to do what I am doing now programmatically - how can I start?" the way VBA does. You can bypass a lot of annoying syntax issues when learning (especially if you've previously done any sort of coding) and focus right on the logic you want to add. It works out pretty well, honestly.

Comment: @enderland: Thanks for your comments! I see that you have a point, and I'll try your approach =) You have many good points in there! =) Do you have a suggestion for how I can go from hard coded ranges to dynamic ones?